# mysqli_real_escape_string - No se que graba en la bbdd

Tags: php

Como buena estudiante, tengo una duda con respecto a la función 
    mysqli_real_escape_string

Mi código:

```
$connn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "test");
1// Obtenemos los datos del formulario, asegurándonos que son válidos.
        $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($connn, $_POST['usuario']);
        //$usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $usuario);
        echo "usuario: $usuario </br>";
```

Bien no está completo pero es que es largo. Mi pregunta son dos.

1. He tenido que generar de nuevo una variable "$connn" para poder poner el parmetro **"$link"**. No se por que cuando me archivo ya tiene un include con "conexion.php". Donde se declara pero no la pilla.
2. ¿Qué dato graba en el BD? Por ejemplo si pongo **"user2525"** supongo que me grabará en la bd **""user2525"** ya que no tiene ningún caracter que escapar. Pero si por ejemplo pongo **"user/25"**, debería grabarme **"user25"** es decir sin los caracteres, ya que solo escapa string? La verdad que si debe ser así no me funciona: :(

Gracias amigos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la documentacion de PHP en Español acerca de `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

> Los caracteres codificados son NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", y Control-Z.

La diagonal `/` no es codificada.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Osea que inicialmente me la debe de grabar tal cual se recupera del formulario excepto si usa ese tipos de variables. ?

Comment: Correcto, solamente los caracteres en la lista son cambiados.

Comment: Jo! Muchísimas gracias! Simplemente no sabía si lo estaba haciendo bien . Gracias @alanfcm

Comment: De nada @EvaMV Solo una cosa, veo que has hecho varias preguntas pero no has aceptado ninguna repuesta.  Es una buena practica aceptar las respuestas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga apoyando.

Comment: Ostras! pues no tenía ni idea de que tenía que aceptarlas. Si eres tan amable de como lo haces yo encantada. Gracias y lo siento de veras.

Comment: No hay problema, a un lado de la resuesta hay un simbolo de check.

Comment: Perfecto! Ya está Gracias Alanfcm!